# Cambiar datos de chartjs según departamento seleccionado

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, chart.js

Holis, tengo unas gráficas las cuales quiero que sea posible cambiar según el departamento seleccionado, pero no logro hacer que esto ocurra.

[image: Gráficas y select]

En este momento me estoy trayendo los datos desde un controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
public function get_products_by_department(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $dep = $request->departamento;
        
        //CONTAMOS LOS ARTÍCULOS MÁS PEDIDOS POR DEPARTAMENTO
        $articulos = Articulo::whereHas('detalleventas', function($q) use($dep){
            $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                    $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                });
            });
        }
        )->with(['detalleventas' => function($q) use($dep){
            $q->whereHas('venta', function($k) use($dep){
                $k->whereHas('cliente', function($o) use($dep){
                    $o->where('departamento', $dep);
                });
            });
        }])->get();

        $artdep = [];
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo) {
            $artdep[] = ['label' => $articulo->nombre, 'data' => count($articulo->detalleventas)];
        };


        //LO ORDENAMOS Y SELECCIONAMOS LOS PRIMEROS 6 DATOS
        $artdep = array_reverse(array_sort($artdep, 'data'));
        $artdep = array_slice($artdep, 0, 6);  
         
        return response()->json($artdep);
    }
}
```

Mi intención es que en `->where('departamento', 'Administración');` yo pueda colocar un $departamento, de forma que el departamento que este seleccionado en el select es el que filtre los datos de las gráficas.

Mi código de la gráfica es:

```
// GRÁFICA DE ARTÍCULOS MÁS PEDIDOS POR DEPARTAMENTO
    const config = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgb(22,83,126)',
            'rgb(188,160,85)',
            'rgb(61,133,198)',
            'rgb(130,57,69)',
            'rgb(249,203,156)',
            'rgb(242,235,236)',
            'rgb(224,102,102)',
            'rgb(57,130,118)',
        ],
        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        data: [],
        }]
      },
      options: {
            animations: {
            tension: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'linear',
                from: 1,
                to: 0,
                loop: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const artChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('artChart').getContext("2d"),
    config,
    );
```

Mi select es:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <select name="departamento" class="form-control js-departamento" id="departamento" name="departamento">
             {{--Construimos las opciones con blade--}}
             <option value="">-- Seleccione el Departamento --</option>
             @foreach($arrayDepartamento as $departamentoitem)
                     <option value="{{ $departamentoitem }}">{{ $departamentoitem }}</option>
             @endforeach
     </select>
</div>
```

Estaba tratando de hacerlo mediante ajax, pero cero lo estoy logrando:

```
<script>
        var dept = $('.js-departamento');

    dept.change(function(event) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_products_by_department') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
            departamento: event.target.value,
            },
            success: function addData(artChart, label, data, artdep) {  
                console.log(data);
                for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
                    artChart.data[i].label.push(label);
                    artChart.data[i].data.push(data);
                }
                        artChart.update();
                    }
                
        });

    });
</script>
```

Pero me está dando el error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

El json resultante es:

[image: json]

Comment: El problema solo es en el ajax?? la consulta es correcta?

Comment: bueno, si hago la consulta desde el controlador y paso los datos a la vista con un array y a chartjs con ``<?php foreach ($catdep as $key => $cat) {echo '"' . $cat['nombre'] . '",';} ?>`` me funciona

Comment: Entonces tienes el json de retorno, favor publícalo en tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿eso no es lo de ``return response()->json($artdep);`` que está en la pregunta?

Comment: Si, pero eso da un JSON. Ese JSON resultante te pido que lo coloques en tu respuesta, para tener como probar el grafico

Comment: @Yussef ahí lo agregué y agregué el error que me está dando el ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función que usas en `success` es incorrecta, de acuerdo al [manual](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), puede recibir 3 parámetros: 1. Datos (respuesta), 2. Estado de la petición, 3. Objeto XHR. Y no es compatible con lo que tienes `success: function addData(artChart, label, data, artdep)`.

Asumo que `artChart` es el objeto que usas para mostrar la gráfica, `label` y `data` deben ser tomados de la respuesta y `artdep` del menú desplegable (aunque realmente no lo usas en el cuerpo de la función).

También parece que el ciclo de 0 a <= 7 va a generar errores, porque en la imagen donde muestras la respuesta hay solo 6 elementos, no 8 y primero debes limpiar todos los datos.

```
let dept = $('.js-departamento');
dept.change(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('get_products_by_department') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            departamento: event.target.value,
        },
        // Agrega el tipo de dato que deseas recibir
        dataType: 'json',
        // Solo necesitas un parámetro
        success: function(data) {
            // Debes recibir un JSON
            console.log(data);

            // Limpiar etiquetas
            artChart.data.labels = [];
            // Limpiar datos
            artChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
            // Recorrer para actualizar
            data.forEach(row => {
                artChart.data.labels.push(row.label);
                artChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(row.data);
            });

            // Actualiza la gráfica
            artChart.update();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
// Crear la gráfica inicial
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const artChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['Uno', 'Dos', 'Tres', 'Cuatro'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Cantidad',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgb(22,83,126)',
                'rgb(188,160,85)',
                'rgb(61,133,198)',
                'rgb(130,57,69)',
                'rgb(249,203,156)',
                'rgb(242,235,236)',
                'rgb(224,102,102)',
                'rgb(57,130,118)',
            ]
        }],
     }
});

// Objeto para actualizar
let otrosDatos = [
    { label: 'Dato 1', data: 5 },
    { label: 'Dato 2', data: 15 },
    { label: 'Dato 3', data: 8 },
    { label: 'Dato 4', data: 7 },
];

// Actualizar al cambiar el selector
$('#depto').on('change', function() {
    // Limpiar etiquetas
    artChart.data.labels = [];
    // Limpiar datos
    artChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
    // Recorrer para actualizar
    otrosDatos.forEach(row => {
        artChart.data.labels.push(row.label);
        artChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(row.data);
    });
    artChart.update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<select id="depto">
    <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="1">Otro depto</option>
</select>

<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: cambié esa parte del código y no me da error en la consola, pero la gráfica no aparece

Comment: en la pregunta está el código de la gráfica

Comment: de verdad disculpa la ignorancia, ¿pero cómo que qué script?

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/

Comment: @KarelixAlejandra, listo, revisa la respuesta actualizada, incluí un ejemplo para probar.